# "ResizeEnd" equivalent for usercontrols

Tags: .net, winforms, resize

I am writing a UserControl. I want to draw the user control when the resize is done. I am not able to find any event equivalent to "ResizeEnd" of a windows form.

Is there any equivalent event for user controls?

*Please note that in this case the parent control of the user control is itself an UserControl, so I cannot convert it (parent user control) into a form. As I am using a framework, I cannot access the form on which this user control will be displayed.*

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If the answer is yes, how? I have the same trouble and posted a possible solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584307/user-control-resize)

Answer (score 8):

There is no equivalent.  A form has a modal sizing loop, started when the user clicks the edge or a corner of the form.  Child controls cannot be resized that way, it only sees changes to its Size property.

Solve this by adding a Sizing property to your user control.  The form can easily assign it from its OnResizeBegin/End() overrides.  Following the Parent property in the UC's Load event until you find the Form is possible too:

```
public bool Resizing { get; set; }

private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (!this.DesignMode) {
    var parent = this.Parent;
    while (!(parent is Form)) parent = parent.Parent;
    var form = parent as Form;
    form.ResizeBegin += (s, ea) => this.Resizing = true;
    form.ResizeEnd += (s, ea) => this.Resizing = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: In may case parent form is also a user control. So I cannot cast the parent control into a form.

Comment: @Ram: that's why the while loop is there.  Did you try it?

Comment: @Hans Passant: this post was given me after my post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584307/user-control-resize). The problem is (using your answer) parent becomes null during cycle and everything fails. Even using `this.FindForm()` gives me null. Do you have another idea?

Comment: @Marco - don't skip the DesignMode test.  Set a breakpoint on this Load event handler and look at the call stack.  The user control may be created too early by an accidental reference to its Handle property.

Comment: @Hans: maybe I understand the reason of this. During runtime, when controls are created, usercontrol (the inner one) is assigned to its parent (outer usercontrol) but at this moment outer control parent is not set yet!!! Do you think I'm right?

Comment: @Hans: do you want to answer my post or do you think is better that we _join_ those posts? I don't know what's better...

Comment: I posted a possible solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584307/user-control-resize): what do you think? Anyway, thanks a lot because your post was the one who led me to the right path :)

Answer (score 1):

The Hans solution is working (and it looks like it is the only way to do it), but it's requires these handlers in every form, which using your control (which is not always acceptable).

So, you can use simple workaround, starting timer when resizing occurs.
Every time size will be changed your timer will be restarted. And only when there will be no size changes for some time (_timer.Interval) it will invoke ResizeFinished() method.

```
    private Timer _timer;

    public MyControl() 
    {
        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 500;
        _timer.Tick += (sender, e) => ResizeFinished();
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void ResizeFinished()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        // Your code
    }
```

As you can see, your code will be invoked only after 500 ms after last size changed invocation.