# User control resize

Tags: c#, events, resize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“ResizeEnd” equivalent for usercontrols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577887/resizeend-equivalent-for-usercontrols)

I feel stupid, but I can't find a solution to a problem that I think it's easy.
I have a user control that (basically) shows an image drawing it during **onPaint** stage:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (img != null)
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, ...);
}
```

When user control is resized, it must perform many actions and one is (given a particular condition) resize image to fit width or height, etc...
Image showed can be "heavy", so when user start resizing and moves mouse, the result is a sort of *slow movement* that's not good for end user.
So I'm wondering if there are windows messages reporting me that the resize operation is starting or completed: if so I can stop redrawing when resize starts and repaint image when resize ends.
Thanks to everybody

**EDITED:**
I tried this:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE = 0x0231;
    const int WM_EXITSIZEMOVE = 0x0232;
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE: resizing = true; break;
        case WM_EXITSIZEMOVE: resizing = false; break;
    }
}
```

but those messages are never called :(

Comment: Can I assume your control is bring resized because it's docked to a panel or form that's being resized?

Comment: @hometoast: yes, but I don't control container form... my control will be used by someone else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post an answer after a long investigation.
First of all I want to thank everybody for your contribution, because your suggestions led me to the right way. Thanks to @Hans Passant too, because his solution on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577887/resizeend-equivalent-for-usercontrols) is an important piece.

**THE PROBLEM:**

- assume we have a usercontrol named **innCnt** (inner control) contained in another usercontrol named **outCnt** (outer control), which in turn should be placed in a form we don't develop (so we can't edit its source)
- assume we have to catch the `EndResize` event in *innCnt*

**CONTRIBUTES:**

- Using `PreProcessMessage` or overriding `WndProc` (thanks to @Cipi):
  I tried these solutions, but I don't receive **WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE** and **WM_EXITSIZEMOVE** messages from Windows
- Trap `MouseDown` and `OnResize` events (thanks to @Cipi):
  It could be ok, but that logic should be moved on *outCnt* because *innCnt* could not receive MouseDown if user is resizing out control or form.
  Anyway I don't like too much this solution
- In the `Load` event of *innCnt*, hook event handlers to the control's form's events (thanks to @hometoast and @pikzen):
  I tried this solution (and the one provided by @Hans [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577887/resizeend-equivalent-for-usercontrols)) but this doesn't work because when *innCnt* is loaded, even in if not in `DesignMode`, his parent is a part of *outCnt*, whose parent **is null** because not ready set!!

**SOLUTION:**
Basicly I had to move @Hans logic inside *outCnt* but not in `Load` event, because even here parent is still null!

```
public class OuterControl
{
    protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.DesignMode)
        {
            Form form = this.FindForm();
            if (form != null)
            {
                form.ResizeBegin += (s, ea) =>innerCnt.Resizing = true;
                form.ResizeEnd += (s, ea) => innerCnt.Resizing = false;
            }
        }
        base.OnParentChanged(e);
    }
}

public class InnerControl
{
    private bool resizing = false;

    public bool Resizing { 
        get { return resizing; }; 
        set {
            resizing = value;
            if (!resizing) {
                // Resizing is just finished:
                // let's do what we need
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Resizing)
        {
            base.OnResize(e);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // Perform resizing actions
        }
    }
}
```

**KNOWN PROBLEMS:**
I'm quite sure that if *outCnt* is placed inside another usercontrol, solution provided won't work...

Comment: the ParentChanged event is only called once ... unless you are writing very weird code. Your solution still depends on the Form's resize/begin.end eventhandlers. for inner controls that may be useless.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested by the [Form.ResizeBegin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizebegin.aspx) and [Form.ResizeEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend.aspx) events.

If you're using WPF, this [thread on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/8453ab09-ce0e-4e14-b30b-3244b51c13c4) might interest you. WPF requires hackery to know when the resize begins/ends

## EDIT

Didn't noticed it was an UserControl ! This question seems to address your problem:
["ResizeEnd" equivalent for usercontrols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577887/resizeend-equivalent-for-usercontrols)

Comment: It's a user control, not a form...

Comment: Marco, right, but you your usercontrol must reside on a form. You could have your usercontrol subscribe to the forms events.

Comment: @hometoast: can you provide an example please? I never did it. And more, my usercontrol is contained in another usercontrol: does this changes something?

Comment: @Marco: Maybe [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577887/resizeend-equivalent-for-usercontrols) is what you're interested in.

Comment: Especially the part about checking whether or not it's in design mode!

Comment: @hometoast: that link is wonderful, but _form_ is null even in runtime!! Even using _this.FindForm()_ I get a null.

Comment: @hometoast: maybe I understand the reason of this. During runtime, when controls are created, usercontrol (the inner one) is assigned to its parent (outer usercontrol) but at this moment outer control parent is not set yet!!!

Comment: Ah. I see how that could be the problem. Perhaps you could hook up the events once in the first call to On_Paint?

Comment: Read my solutions and tell me what you think about it. I really appreciated your help, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

In the Load event of your UserControl, hook event handlers to the control's form's events.

Apologies, I have a VB project open, I'll convert it in the answer when I get a moment.

```vb
Private Sub UserControl1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler Me.FindForm.ResizeBegin, AddressOf MyFormsResizeBegin
    AddHandler Me.FindForm.ResizeEnd, AddressOf MyFormsResizeEnd
End Sub

Private Sub MyFormsResizeBegin(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'tell your control to wait.
End Sub
Private Sub MyFormsResizeEnd(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'say everything is ok to continue

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I mentioned before my container is not a form and my usercontrol will be given to other people, so I can't _force_ them to do anything; and I don't know who's my parent...

Comment: Not the immediate container, no. But eventually, the user control (and it's parents) have to reside on a form. The FindForm() method is used exactly for that. Not knowing how many layers deep of .Parent() you have

Comment: Read my solutions and tell me what you think about it. I really appreciated your help, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

You really want to do that (windows messages)? :D

First, you cant do that like overriding `PreProcessMessage` or `WndProc` because I'm guessing the containing form will trap the resizing start/end message (or any other messages) so your control will not get any. The way to do that is to implement `IMessageFilter` interface on your control. Then you will get this method in your control in which you can switch through the received message m:

`public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)`

Then at the control constructor add: `Application.AddMessageFilter(this);` and there you go, now Application thread is calling `PreFilterMessage` method and passing it the received message.

**Another idea:**

If you let the users change the controls size with their mouse, you can trap MouseDown and set `bool MouseIsDown` flag Then in `OnResize` you can check

```
if(MouseIsDown && Resizing == false)
{
    Resizing = true;
    //Start Resizing only once
}
```

And on MouseUp:

```
if(Resizing == true && MouseIsDown == true)
{
    Resizing = MouseIsDown = false;
    //End the resizing once
}
```

Comment: Read my solutions and tell me what you think about it. I really appreciated your help, thanks a lot!!